# How do you edit Custom Build Definition Template using TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

If I create a custom Build Definition Template from the context menu below, how does one actually edit it?

[image: Context Menu]

I can see I can delete it, but not edit. Are Overwrite or Delete & Recreate the only means to edit the Template? Seems a little severe... Neither option seems to give me historical tracking...

[image: Custom Build template]
Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/features-timeline this is a new feature in the initial phase that will be enhanced with 2017 Update 2 and later (honestly I haven't noticed it arrived in Update 1).

Comment: Well, bummer. Love that MS seem to introduce half-baked features which are then solidified in a later release... :( Unless someone comes up with a miracle answer, I'll accept this answer later on.

Comment: If you are curious there are some papers around. Shortly, they deliver every three weeks in the cloud (VSTS) and every few months (about three) they snapshot the state, run through additional tests, and deliver as TFS

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you actually can "edit" them, by creating a new template with the same name and basically overwrite the old one.

So you could:

1. Create a new build definition, using your existing template.
2. Make changes
3. Create a new template from the build definition with *the same name* as your current template.

All according to [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7aad959d-5fa5-44d4-a8ba-c43629855169/how-to-edit-a-custom-build-definition-template?forum=tfsbuild)